# How to remove grub without access to Windows

Tags: boot, grub2

I have been dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 on my Surface Pro 2. 
But as the drivers on Ubuntu aren't that great for the surface, I decided to remove Ubuntu.

However they way I removed Ubuntu was to delete the partition from Windows and then expand the Windows partition to use all the storage.

When I restarted the computer it booted straight into a grub console (Minimal BASH-like) grub>

The problem is now I want to boot Windows 8 as that's the only operating system on the device right now. How can I do that ?

I have successfully booted a Ubuntu Live USB from that menu. I did that because I wanted to run boot-repair or lilo from within the live environment to be able to remove grub and get the MBR back. However none of that worked.

I now feel a little stock, and I'm out of ideas on what to do next. 
Can I reinstall grub somehow so I can boot windows?

Ps

- I don't think I can boot a windows recovery media as I'm not able to get anywhere else but to this grub menu. That means, no BIOS/EFI menus are accessible.
- I can't resize the windows partition from Ubuntu as it keeps saying something about Windows is in hibernate mode, and therefore the partition can only be mounted as read only..

The screen I see when I boot looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just boot from Windows DVD and do a Startup repair.
On most of the systems repeatedly pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> key brings up the boot menu. Give it a try.
A hiberated partition cannot be mounted. You have hibernated Windows 8 instead of shutting it down.

Comment: How? I can't access BIOS/EFI menu. As the the computer don't offer one of those "Press F11 to change startup", instead I have to hold down Volume Up + Power to access EFI menu, but that doesn't work. It always to straight to the grub console

Comment: Can you see the GRUB menu

Comment: No, only a screen like this one:
http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/img/1388996380.png

Comment: Hardware Info Please

Comment: which hardware info are you interested in ?
Most specs can be seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_2

Mine is a 128 GB with 4 GB Ram. Intel Core i5 4200.

Comment: Do you see Surface Logo when you turn on the system

Comment: Yes I do. The Surface Logo displays, and then the grub console comes up.

Comment: After you get to grub prompt, type "boot" (without quote) and press enter

Comment: Got the following response:
You need to load the kernel first

Comment: try these **root(hd0,0)** Press Enter **makeactive** Press Enter
**chainloader -force + 1** Press Enter 
**boot** Press Enter

Comment: after the first enter, im getting a "cannot find command root

Comment: Sorry then! The only way left is to repair MBR.

Answer (score 5):

I have Surface Pro 1 with Windows 8.1. I resized the Windows partition and installed Ubuntu 13.10, but, like the person who posted the question (Steffen Christensen) I found the driver support very bad and WiFi always freeze my tablet .

So, I just formatted the Ubuntu partition, and could not remove Grub 2 boot loader. I did some research online and made this solution myself and fixed my tablet with it, and it is working great:

When tablet is powered off, put the Windows 8.1 Recovery USB drive in the USB port, hold down `volume down` and `power` for some seconds till it powers on. You'll see the Surface logo. It will take few minutes till the bios / UEFI menu starts.

Choose language and keyboard as English. Go to `Troubleshoot`->`Advanced Options`->`Command Prompt`. Enter these commands:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

(If you have more than one physical disk, choose the disk with Windows installation on it. In my case, only one disk was in the list: disk 0.)

```
select disk 0
list partition
select partition  x
```

(Where `x` is the number of the partition listed by the list partition command. You must choose the partition with type marked as the System ( EFI partition ), which in my case was number 2.)

```
assign letter=u
```

(`U` is the drive letter you wish to assign to the EFI partition.)

```
exit
```

(This will exit the `diskpart` command. You will still be on the command prompt window.)

```
u:
```

(Take you to the U: drive.)

```
dir
```

(Shows list of directories in drive U: - you must see a directory named `efi`.)

```
cd efi
dir
```

(Shows list of directories in folder `efi` - you must see a directory named `ubuntu`.)
Now we must delete GRUB in its official/proper location `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` for Ubuntu. If Secure Boot was active, deleting `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` would be necessary instead. In fact, deleting the whole `EFI/ubuntu` directory, or at least renaming it, would do the job in any case. We will delete the entire directory:

```
rd /s /q  u:\efi\ubuntu    
cd c:\windows\system32
Bootrec/fixmbr 
Bootrec/fixboot 
exit
```

Done. Now the command prompt window is closed. Now choose 'Turn off your PC'
and then restart. It should be back normal.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to boot into windows again u can use grub boot loader or windows boot loader

for grub boot loader

=> u need ubuntu live usb and use " load ubuntu without install"
then install boot-repair and repair grub
u can see it here how it is done https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

for windows boot loader(its lengthy but very easy one than grub)

=> u need a windows 8.1 repair disc(if u created one when using windows) or windows 8.1 live usb or cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to repair but not to use startup repair it wont work mostly instead repair using windows command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again